# Negative confidence intervals in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

( I have searched many pages to get the answer for this , but in vain )

Please help me understand what a negative confidence interval actually means and how it can be interpreted, especially when the variable has a positive correlation with the dependent variable. 
Below is the data and its structure.

```
'data.frame':   251 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ BodyFat: num  12.3 6.1 25.3 10.4 28.7 20.9 19.2 12.4 4.1 11.7 ...
 $ Weight : num  154 173 154 185 184 ...
 $ Chest  : num  93.1 93.6 95.8 101.8 97.3 ...
 $ Abdomen: num  85.2 83 87.9 86.4 100 94.4 90.7 88.5 82.5 88.6 ...
 $ Hip    : num  94.5 98.7 99.2 101.2 101.9 ...
 $ Thigh  : num  59 58.7 59.6 60.1 63.2 66 58.4 60 62.9 63.1 ...
 $ Biceps : num  32 30.5 28.8 32.4 32.2 35.7 31.9 30.5 35.9 35.6 ...

> cor(body) # Shows positive correlation values between variables.
          BodyFat    Weight     Chest   Abdomen       Hip     Thigh    Biceps
BodyFat 1.0000000 0.6199217 0.7009325 0.8253710 0.6384826 0.5568926 0.4821925
Weight  0.6199217 1.0000000 0.8913628 0.8742672 0.9294444 0.8505810 0.7851911
Chest   0.7009325 0.8913628 1.0000000 0.9098518 0.8207654 0.7055343 0.7072069
Abdomen 0.8253710 0.8742672 0.9098518 1.0000000 0.8593542 0.7379840 0.6564326
Hip     0.6384826 0.9294444 0.8207654 0.8593542 1.0000000 0.8837342 0.7173519
Thigh   0.5568926 0.8505810 0.7055343 0.7379840 0.8837342 1.0000000 0.7401922
Biceps  0.4821925 0.7851911 0.7072069 0.6564326 0.7173519 0.7401922 1.0000000

> summary(fitb)

Call:
lm(formula = BodyFat ~ Weight + Chest + Abdomen + Hip + Thigh + 
    Biceps, data = body)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.7135  -3.1515  -0.1814   3.3503  10.1434 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -52.28196    9.30962  -5.616 5.31e-08 ***
Weight       -0.16593    0.03811  -4.354 1.97e-05 ***
Chest        -0.04360    0.09863  -0.442    0.659    
Abdomen       1.01866    0.07489  13.603  < 2e-16 ***
Hip          -0.07026    0.14124  -0.497    0.619    
Thigh         0.21373    0.13010   1.643    0.102    
Biceps        0.17409    0.16184   1.076    0.283    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.372 on 244 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7317,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7251 
F-statistic: 110.9 on 6 and 244 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Below i get a negative confidence interval for Weight, which had positive correlation in the first place.

What does that actually mean ? Please help me interpret this.

```
> confint(fitb)
                  2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept) -70.6194423 -33.9444834
Weight       -0.2409986  -0.0908677
Chest        -0.2378653   0.1506702
Abdomen       0.8711559   1.1661630
Hip          -0.3484608   0.2079337
Thigh        -0.0425293   0.4699805
Biceps       -0.1446869   0.4928583
```